# Short Story About A Newspaper Carrier Whose Newspapers Get Wet Due To Rain - Printed in an Early 1970s 8th Grade English Literature Textbook

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I am searching for the title of a short story that is about a newspaper carrier who is a male child that is approximately the age of 10 to 16. In the short story, the newspaper carrier is delivering newspapers to various people on his newspaper delivery route. Due to rain that is falling while the newspaper carrier is delivering his newspapers, the newspaper carrier's newspapers become wet. The newspaper carrier comes to the residence of an elderly woman with his newspapers. The elderly woman may have been one of the people that the newspaper carrier is supposed deliver newspapers to. The elderly woman helps the newspaper carrier by attempting to dry the newspapers. In the short story, the elderly woman may have provided a meal for the newspaper carrier. The short story was printed in an English literature textbook for 8th graders that was published in the early 1970s. The English literature textbook that the short story was printed in also may have had in it the play titled "The Diary of Anne Frank" and 1 or more short stories by Edgar Allan Poe such as "The Tell-Tale Heart" and/or "The Raven". The English literature textbook in which the short story was printed in may have been titled "Adventures for Readers Book 2" which was published in 1973 by Harcourt Brace Jovanovich.

Comment: This sounds a bit like a scene in *[Henry Huggins and the Paper Route](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_and_the_Paper_Route)* by Beverly Cleary, but the scene with the damp newspapers has his mother and father helping him, not an old woman on the route.

Comment: Apparently, Henry interacted more with Mrs. Peabody, an older lady on his route, in [*Henry and the Clubhouse*](https://www.pluggedin.com/book-reviews/henry-and-the-clubhouse/), the next book in the series, but I haven't found evidence that his papers get wet.